# Protected USB connectors?

Tags: usb, connector, cables, environmental-sealing

Do USB connectors come in protected versions suitable for damp, vibration prone environments?  If so, what terms should I use when searching for them?

If not, what are my options for meeting the USB wiring and connectors standards without standard USB connectors?  Can I use different cables and connectors and "make up" for the electrical differences by terminating the ends differently?

Comment: What kind of rating do you really need?  The IEC IP Code is a great way to determine what you need.  Bear in mind all of those ratings are done at 25C.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code

Comment: You can improve the question by specifying a specific property you are looking for in the title and the question. At the moment it is very broad and can not help others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like this?

[image: Industrial USB]

These are really just normal USB connectors, but with a strong, waterproof connector over the top of them. This holds them in place despite vibration, protects them from mechanical abuse, and keeps the water out.

I think the key word you need is 'industrial'.  Farnell stock a [bunch of them](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/results.jsp?N=2031%20202829&Ntk=gensearch&Ntt=usb&Ntx=mode%20matchallpartial).

Also, take a look at the [Bulgin datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2865.pdf). From this, you can get the part numbers for the panel mount, and cable mount versions of the connector.

Comment: Looks good, except I'm now having trouble finding cable mount receptacles and plugs.  I need both sides to mate and not be panel mounts.  I've also tried "shrouded" and "latching" as keywords, but am still finding it difficult to get what I want.  I'll keep searching though.  Thanks!

Comment: @AdamDavis Added a link to the Bulgin datasheet.

Comment: I would recommend search terms *environmentally sealed USB cable*.  It found some cables and connectors that may be useful for you (including Bulgin Buccaneer, which Rocketmagnet suggested).  Thumbing through DigiKey, Mouser, Newark, etc catalog would help too.

Comment: http://www.molex.com/molex/products/group?key=sealed_connectors&channel=products it looks like they have sealed cables, including USB: http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=industrial_usb_type_a_and_b_plugs_and_receptacles&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=sealed_connectors.

Comment: "nema rated" and "IP rated" are also good search terms